# How can i turn on & off gps in WP7, when my app is on & off?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, gps

i am working on app, for which i need to switch on & off GPS, means that when user open my app then gps start working & when switched off the app ,gps automatically turned off.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean '*how do I turn the GPS on/off in my app, even if the user has it off in Settings?*', you can't. 
The user must opt to enable the GPS themselves first, then (according to marketplace rules) you must ask them if you can use GPS functions, AND there must be a way for them to turn GPS off for your app, inside your app.

If you're just asking how you can use the GPS, the class you want is `GeoCoordianteWatcher`

The simplest way to use it is:

```
var watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.Default);
watcher.PositionChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate>>(watcher_PositionChanged);
watcher.StatusChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs>(watcher_StatusChanged);
watcher.Start();
```

Although looking into the Reactive ways to use it isn't a bad idea.

Comment: yes i want when my app starts it ask user to switch on gps! How can i achieve this?

Comment: You could use `MessageBox.Show("Please turn on your GPS to use this application")`, but they would have to _exit_ your app to turn it on.

You would need to check out the watcher status to see if it is `GeoPositionStatus.Disabled` to tell if the GPS is off, I think.

Comment: not a good solution! any other way like : like slide bar appears which have buttons to turned on gps??

Comment: You cannot turn the GPS (or any other of the hardware options) on/off within your app. It isn't possible. It's a limitation by the WP7 API

Comment: thanks! hope Microsoft resolve this issue, other wise i moved on to android ;)

Comment: @Aqib: I don't think MS is going to 'solve' a privacy-protection. Have you looked at the policies in Android?